Unable to define data collection endpoint and data collection rule in azure
I have created  a log analytics workspace and table using the following commands in my pipeline :-
az monitor log-analytics workspace create --resource-group $(ResourceGroupName) --workspace-name $(LogAnalyticsWorkspaceName)
az monitor log-analytics workspace table create --resource-group $(ResourceGroupName) \
            --workspace-name $(LogAnalyticsWorkspaceName) -n $(LogAnalyticsGWCustomTableName)  \
            --columns RawData=string TimeGenerated=datetime LogLevel=string --retention-time 90

where the variables are defined in the environment files.
I am trying to create a data collection rule as below :-
az monitor data-collection rule create --resource-group $(ResourceGroupName) --location $(Location) --name 'gw-d-dcr' --rule-file '/resourcegroup-deployments/custom-loganalytics/customlogsgatewayvm-$(parameters.environment).parameters.json'

where the --rule file has below content :-
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "dataCollectionRules_gw_d_dcr_name": {
        "defaultValue": "gw-d-dcr",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "dataCollectionEndpoints_cre_gw_d_dce_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/ea273087-6293-4fc2-bfe7-aa29ea8ab4bf/resourceGroups/lz-cre-d-rg/providers/Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionEndpoints/cre-gw-d-dce",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "workspaces_cre_d_law_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/ea273087-6293-4fc2-bfe7-aa29ea8ab4bf/resourceGroups/lz-cre-d-rg/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/cre-d-law",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRules",
        "apiVersion": "2023-03-11",
        "name": "[parameters('dataCollectionRules_gw_d_dcr_name')]",
        "location": "westeurope",
        "tags": {
            "AppName": "CRE",
            "Billing code": "NL02264",
            "Business Application CI": "CI0030939",
            "CIA": "112",
            "ContactMail": "laurens.de.vries@nl.abnamro.com",
            "ContactPhone": "+31624536181",
            "Environment": "Development",
            "Owner": "laurens.de.vries@nl.abnamro.com",
            "Provider": "CBSP Azure"
        },
        "kind": "Linux",
        "properties": {
            "dataCollectionEndpointId": "[parameters('dataCollectionEndpoints_cre_gw_d_dce_externalid')]",
            "streamDeclarations": {
                "Custom-Text-gw_customlogs_CL": {
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "name": "TimeGenerated",
                            "type": "datetime"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "RawData",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "dataSources": {
                "logFiles": [
                    {
                        "streams": [
                            "Custom-Text-gw_customlogs_CL"
                        ],
                        "filePatterns": [
                            "/data/web/cre/LogFiles/ACBS/*.log",
                            "/data/web/cre/LogFiles/ACBS/*.err",
                            "/data/web/cre/LogFiles/CRAS/*.log",
                            "/data/web/cre/LogFiles/CRAS/*.err",
                            "/data/web/cre/LogFiles/RAPID/*.log",
                            "/data/web/cre/LogFiles/RAPID/*.err",
                            "/home/ctrmazure/software/ctm/dailylog/daily*"
                        ],
                        "format": "text",
                        "settings": {
                            "text": {
                                "recordStartTimestampFormat": "ISO 8601"
                            }
                        },
                        "name": "Custom-Text-gw_customlogs_CL"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "destinations": {
                "logAnalytics": [
                    {
                        "workspaceResourceId": "[parameters('workspaces_cre_d_law_externalid')]",
                        "name": "la--771413343"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "dataFlows": [
                {
                    "streams": [
                        "Custom-Text-gw_customlogs_CL"
                    ],
                    "destinations": [
                        "la--771413343"
                    ],
                    "transformKql": "source",
                    "outputStream": "Custom-gw_customlogs_CL"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
] }

There is an already defined data collection endpoint in our environemnt. But i want to create a new one but not able to find the correct way. Please help in setting it all up in correct manner. Thanks.

Is the issue with using az monitor data-collection rule command? @Aviator


There is an already defined data collection endpoint in our environment. But I want to create a new one but not able to find the correct way:

There are a couple of approaches for your requirement.
Firstly, obtain the resource ID of a created data collection rule through portal or CLI with the below command.
Portal view:

az monitor data-collection endpoint show
az monitor data-collection endpoint show -n firstep --resource-group Jahnavi

Note: Pass --query id with the above CLI command to obtain only the ID property.


Now copy the resource ID and edit the rule.json file's property called dataCollectionEndpoints_cre_gw_d_dce_externalid with the newly obtained ID.
Save all the changes and achieve your requirement usingaz monitor data-collection rule create command.
Alternatively, you can use the PowerShell methodInvoke-AzRestMethod to call the existing DCR and obtain the ID which is detailed here in MSDoc.
